# better way of limiting what modules/tabs the user (based on its type) can view

Tags: php, html, usertype

Is there a better way of limiting what modules/tabs the user (based on its type) can view aside from this? This has been my algorithm ever since I started web development.

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <?php 
      if($_SESSION['user_type']==1){ 
        echo '<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/ci_tms/controller_delegate/index" style="color:white;">Delegate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/ci_tms/controller_monitor/index" style="color:white;">Monitor</a>
        </li>'; 
      } 
      ?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="http://localhost/ci_tms/controller_dashboard/remove_credentials" style="color:white;">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Basically, that's how it should mostly work. You generally also want to stop unauthorised users at every level, though, so even if they can't see the tab but visit the link anyway, they will be blocked. Research 'User Roles' or check this symfony doc page:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html